# QRコードログイン機能でログインされたデバイスがPCだった場合について

Tags: qr-code, 認証認可

LINEやDiscordなどのQRコードログイン機能で、PCでアプリを開きQRコードを出して、それをログイン済みのスマホで読み取ることでPC側でもログインができる機能を見たことがある方もいると思います。ではこの時、PCではログイン済みでスマホ側ではログインがまだ済んでいないときのQRコードログイン機能は実装可能でしょうか？

状況としては以下のような場合です：

- あるPCアプリでログインが必要なのでPC側で一回ログインする。
- そのPCアプリではスマホからブラウザを開いて行う操作が必要なのでスマホでもログインする。
- この時、既に一回PC側でログイン作業（IDとパスワード入力）を行っているのでスマホで再度それらを入力する手間は省略したい。

この時にログイン済みのPCからQRコードを表示して、それをスマホのカメラアプリで読み取るとスマホでブラウザが開きログインされた状態にするような機能は実装可能でしょうか？いろいろQRコードログインで調べていますが、その殆どがスマホ側でログインがされており、PCでログインする時にPC側でQRコードを出してそれを読み取るというものです。QRコードを表示するのはPCのまま、ログイン済みのデバイスをPC、ログインする機器をスマホにすることはできますでしょうか？表示するQRコードにログイン情報を持たせたり、ワンタイムトークンなどを使って実装できるのかどうかが分からず、質問させていただきました。
よろしくお願いします。